# “Error: Connection error. Please try again.” when uploading a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a json file through the web UI but I am receiving this generic error message: *Error: Connection error. Please try again.*. Can you please let me know what's wrong.

```
Job Id = job_VmEiQY0xYPWjjLa-Knaz-C3INNA
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your job encountered a transient error in one of our data centers that prevented us from loading your data into BigQuery. This problem appears to be resolved as of 2014-02-12.

As always, we recommend that you write client code that retries on error. We also recommend that you generate your own job IDs when loading data. That way, if you encounter an error, you can retry with the same job ID and be assured that at most one of your attempts to load the data will succeed.

Comment: You probably mean 2014-02-12. The error message has been fixed, it was a problem with my schema. Thanks.